# How do I set nodata with custom color for gdal_translate and gdal2tilespy?

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate, gdalbuildvrt

I start with a bunch of 1-bit geotiff files that I had to convert to 8-bit RGB tiff files to use with GDAL. Then I tried to set borders to red (content is in black and white so I can't use those) and do

```
gdal_translate -a_nodata '200 0 0' -of vrt red.tiff nodata.vrt

gdalbuildvrt -srcnodata '200 0 0' -vrtnodata '200 0 0' -hidenodata -addalpha nodata.vrt trans.vrt

gdal2tiles.py -a "200,0,0" trans.vrt ...
```

But I am only able to hide nodata if it is in grayscale(ex. rgb(200,200,200)) I think the color information is just lost in the gdal_translate process. Is there any way to verify what happened and make gdal work with nodata that has custom colors?

Answer (score 1):

You can verify what GDAL interprets as nodata with gdalinfo

```
gdalinfo red.tiff
gdalinfo nodata.vrt
gdalinfo trans.vrt
```

Take also care to use a recent GDAL version. There was a bug that made GDAL to read sometimes only the first value of nodata and repeated it to the rest (200 0 0 -> 200 200 200). Unfortunately I could not find when it was corrected but GDAL 1.10 or higher for sure does not have this bug.